# Subset of Crypto++ library for mobile usage (iOS, Android)

Tags: c++, ios, android-ndk, crypto++

I need to use some RSA signature scheme for an cross platform library used in an Android and iPhone project. After looking around I've chosen cryptopp, but it is far too big for static linking. Thus I added source and headers to my project in order to only link the relevant parts into my lib. It's still adding a few MB in release build to the final lib.

1. Is there an easier or more effective way of brining down the size of a library or cryptopp in particular?
2. I'm not in detail familiar with template generation during compiling. But I remember that templates can add quite a lot of code. Is there a way to stop/improve this (compiler options?)?
3. If I want to manually remove all source/header files from the project that are not used by my simple usecase, are there any tools to help? Digging through cryptopp with its templates would take quite some time and I'm always in favor of automatic processes ;)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use crypto++ (and there are many good reasons you'd want to) this is probably a scenario where you're just best off letting the linkers do their job. I was concerned about this some time ago, and I could not do any better by hand than the optimizing linkers could.

I confirmed this by dusting off my old test app that uses crypto++ to generate a new random RSA key, sign a string and verify that string. Here are the numbers I see:

- libcryptopp.a - crypto++ built for release as a static library using clang++ against the iOS SDK 5.0. There was no special attmept to minimize size, just built with -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden and -Os: **22.5MB**
- Empty app from the default iOS single view template, built with -Os: **34KB**
- The same empty app with "self test" code added that generates a keypair, signs (and therefore hashes) a string using RSA/SHA256, hex encodes it, prints the signature, decodes the signature and verifies the signature over the original string, built with -Os against the libcryptopp.a from my first bullet above: **389KB**

The linker seems to be doing a good job here. If you're seeing something drastically different, make sure you're really looking at release binaries.

Answer (score 0):

> RSA Signatures ... in an Android and iPhone project. After looking around I've chosen cryptopp...

Related (from the Crypto++ wiki): [Android (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Android_%28Command_Line%29) and [iOS (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/iOS_%28Command_Line%29).

> Is there an easier or more effective way of bringing down the size of a library or cryptopp in particular?

No. The compiler and libtool on iOS have no way to tell what you may (or may not) need, so you get everything in the archive. Ditto for the GNU tools provided on Android.

> I'm not in detail familiar with template generation during compiling. But I remember that templates can add quite a lot of code. Is there a way to stop/improve this (compiler options?)?

No easy way. But you can go though the source code and pull out explicit template instantiations. You want to find objects instantiated with `CRYPTOPP_DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS`. You can see how its defined in [config.h](https://sourceforge.net/p/cryptopp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/c5/config.h).

But I would not worry about it since you can get the linker to discard most (or all?) unused code from a static library.

> If I want to manually remove all source/header files from the project that are not used by my simple use case, are there any tools to help?

No, I'm not aware of any tools to do it (similar to Boost's `bcp`). I've tried this in the past, and gave up in frustration.

What you did not ask: how do you reduce the size of the final binary when linking to the static version of Crypto++. Here are the answers:

- Both

  - Modify `GNUmakefile`
  - `CXXFLAGS += -Os`
  - `CXXFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`
- iOS

  - Modify `GNUmakefile`
  - `CXXFLAGS += -gfull`
  - `LDFLAGS += -dead_strip`
- Android

  - `CXXFLAGS += -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL`
  - run `arm-linux-androideabi-strip` with `--strip-debug`, `--strip-unneeded` or `--strip-all` on your final library or executable

Both techniques are covered in the Wiki pages. If you are working on Linux, there's another wiki page to cover size reduction and stripping at [Crypto++ Linux](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Linux).

For more reading, see [Tuning for Performance and Responsiveness](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html) (for iOS), [arm-eabi-strip and binary size](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/ZHFLHHXihXI/wHwYFK_6oA0J), and [Removing unused functions/dead code](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2003-08/msg00128.html) (for Android and Linux).